# How to print/export a scatter plot with the a specific linewidth?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to export a scatter plot that shows the data points as small crosses ('x'). When I specify the linewidth of the crosses in the code it changes the linewidth in the displayed figure, as it should be. But when I export the figure with 'print' the linewidth is always this, I assume set to 1.

I printed the figure as PNG, EPS and JPEG and the result is the same.

Example code:

```
x=rand(5,1);

y=rand(5,1);

scatter(x,y,150,'x','linewidth',20)

print(['Test.png'],'-dpng','-r600' )
```

Edit: I am using MATLAB 2018b.

Comment: It works just fine for in R2014b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this bug in 2018b. This screenshot of my desktop shows the figure (left), exporting the figure using Matlab's UI (middle) and exporting figure using Matlab's `print()`. The line width is clearly different in the latter.

[image]

While I cannot tell you *why* this happens, this still can be resolved using the excellent `export_fig` function from [this package](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig). Here is the output using `export_fig test_ef.png`:

[image]

Comment: I also experienced the bug in 2018b and the package fixes it for me as well. Thank you!